# About Limiting Rss Feed

Tags: php

I want only the latest 5 feeds to be shown on my website.
I am using the following code to fetch rss feed... Can any one help to limited feeds to be shown... Thank You In ADVANCE :)

CODE THAT AM USING

```
<?php
 require_once('rss_fetch.inc');

 $url = 'http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss';

 $rss = fetch_rss($url);

 echo "Site: ", $rss->channel['title'], "<br>\n";
 foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
   $title = $item['title'];
   $url   = $item['link'];
   $desc = $item['description'];
   $category = $item['category'];
   echo "<a href=$url>$title</a>$desc <br/>CATEGORY : $category <br/><br/> ";
 }
?>
```

Comment: turn the `foreach` into a loop that uses a counter that goes up to 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit it using `foreach`?

```
 foreach ($rss->items as $i => $item ) { // use $i as counter
   $title = $item['title'];
   $url   = $item['link'];
   $desc = $item['description'];
   $category = $item['category'];
   echo "<a href=$url>$title</a>$desc <br/>CATEGORY : $category <br/><br/> ";
   if($i == 4) break; // add this, == 4 is because $i starts from 0
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to limit the number of posts, you just need to keep track of them and break out of the foreach loop when applicable, e.g.

```
<?php
 require_once('rss_fetch.inc');

 $url = 'http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss';

 $rss = fetch_rss($url);

 echo "Site: ", $rss->channel['title'], "<br>\n";
 $numposts = 0;
 $maxposts = 5;
 foreach ($rss->items as $item ) {
   $numposts++;
   if ($numposts<=$maxposts) {
     $title = $item['title'];
     $url   = $item['link'];
     $desc = $item['description'];
     $category = $item['category'];
     echo "<a href=$url>$title</a>$desc <br/>CATEGORY : $category <br/><br/> ";
   } else {
     break;
   }
 }
?>
```